# Is it possible to create new type variable without struct?

Tags: c++, c

Here is what i got but when i check type it displays "struct MyVarName"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
typedef struct { char text[15];} MyVarName;
int  g = 0;
int main(void) {
    MyVarName a = { "super" };
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(g).name() << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to define your own variable type and then use it as any other variable?

Print, assign new value.. etc.

Comment: Why are you using `typeid(...).name()`, what exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Code is [tag:c++]: why the [tag:c] tag?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. I also feel wrong with assigning a pointer to array.

Comment: _Is it possible to define your own variable type and then use it as any other variable?_, well that's one of the purposes of C++.

Comment: can you show the code that you would like to write? As it stands the question is completely unclear

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi That's initializating a char array from a string literal that does not exceed the size of the array, not assignment. It is valid.

Comment: The whole point of `struct` is to define your own types. So you are pretty much asking if you can define your own types without doing what is required to define your own type.

Comment: What `typeid(a).name()` returns is not defined by `C++` it is down to the compiler writers. It can be different for every compiler.

Comment: "Yeah, i don't want to use stuct. Doesn't look good." Then use a language whose syntax suits you better aesthetically.

Comment: @AESTHETICS In C++, user-defined types are introduced with keyword `class`, `struct`, or `union`. It's unclear what you don't like about them, and what you're actually trying to achieve. If you explain better what "doesn't look good" means, there might be a way to answer you.

Comment: `std::string` is a class, just like your "struct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C:

```
typedef char newtype[20];

void foo(void)
{
    newtype a;
}
```

Comment: Of course, be aware that this doesn't really introduce a new type. It introduces a new name, `newtype`, for the existing type `char[20]`.

Comment: @Angew of course - typedef creates an alias. But there is no way to create the type like "int' in the C (maybe except own dialect & compiler modification)

Comment: This is what came up to me when i started thinking about new type. Would have to write my own compiler to do what i really had in mind.

Comment: No :). It behaves like a new type. My comment you can actually ignore as it does not make any difference for you. When it will start - you will not need our help, as your programming & C knowledge will be on the much higher level :)

Answer (score 2):

[The result of `std::type_info::name()` is implementation-defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) and could be anything, including a mangled name, the empty string, or a recipe for lasagna.

For example, GCC [gives](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af4ead7be9b798cf):

```
9MyVarName
i
```

Apparently yours is taking a C-like approach and calling it `struct MyVarName`, which is what you'd have to write to reference the type in C.

Simply don't rely on it for this kind of thing. C++ does not pretend to have meaningful *reflection*.

Besides that, there is nothing wrong with your code. You *did* define a new type. There are ways to introduce new types that don't require the creation of a class type (i.e. with `struct` or `class`), but these all involve aliasing existing types with `typedef` or `using`, and are thus limited. They won't allow you to create a complex type like `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. I noticed GCC gave different result after i posted the question.

Comment: @AESTHETICS: Simply reading documentation would have revealed the fact ahead of time

Comment: I asked if it is possible create new type variable without using struct either way. Code is just an example of it being taken as a struct when printing out typeinfo of variable.

Comment: @AESTHETICS: It _is_ a struct (actually a class), obviously, so I don't know what else you expected. There are ways to introduce new types that don't require the creation of a class type, but these all involve aliasing existing types with `typedef` or `using`, and are thus limited. At this point it's really unclear whether you're complaining about the way you created a type, or complaining about the behaviour of `typeinfo`.